# Break up long line of text into lines of fixed width in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, text, python-2.7, format

How would I break up a long string, at the spaces where possible, inserting hyphens if not, with an indent for all lines apart from the first line?

so, for a working function, breakup():

```
splitme = "Hello this is a long string and it may contain an extremelylongwordlikethis bye!"
breakup(bigline=splitme, width=20, indent=4)
```

would output:

```
Hello this is a long
    string and it
    may contain an
    extremelylongwo-
    rdlikethis bye!
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a standard Python module for doing this: [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap):

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> splitme = "Hello this is a long string and it may contain an extremelylongwordlikethis bye!"
>>> textwrap.wrap(splitme, width=10)
['Hello this', 'is a long', 'string and', 'it may', 'contain an', 'extremelyl', 'ongwordlik', 'ethis bye!']
>>>
```

It doesn't insert hyphens when breaking words, though. The module has a shortcut function `fill` which concatenates the list produced by `wrap` so it's just one string.

```
>>> print textwrap.fill(splitme, width=10)
Hello this
is a long
string and
it may
contain an
extremelyl
ongwordlik
ethis bye!
```

To control indentation, use keyword arguments `initial_indent` and `subsequent_indent`:

```
>>> print textwrap.fill(splitme, width=10, subsequent_indent=' ' * 4)
Hello this
    is a
    long
    string
    and it
    may co
    ntain
    an ext
    remely
    longwo
    rdlike
    this
    bye!
>>>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for the explanation and examples.  I didn't know about the textwrap module.  It's almost what I want, shame it doesn't support hyphens for long words.